# DataNode doesn't start in one of the slaves

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to configure hadoop with 5 slaves. After I run start-dfs.sh in the master there is only one slave node which doesn't run DataNode. I tried looking for some difference in  the configuration files in that node but I didn't find anything.

Comment: Log on to the node that has failed to start a DataNode and look in the logs (and share and error messages if you're still stuck)

Comment: OK, I got it. The configuration files had a difference (My bad, sorry). The hadoop.tmp.dir was set to a invalid directory (it couldn't be created). I fixed it and now it runs DataNode. Nevertheless I have this problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/433862/hadoop-port-appears-open-locally-but-not-remotelly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There WAS a difference in the configuration files! In the core-site.xml the hadoop.tmp.dir variable was set to a invalid directory so it couldn't be created when the DataNode was started. Lesson learned: look in the logs (Thanks Chris)